# Correct command opts for xorriso

Tags: 20.04, iso

I've been toiling for the entire day trying to get xorriso to work.   What I am doing is modifying the grub.cfg and inserting some custom user-data and meta-data files for autoinstall testing on ubuntu-20.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso.   I didn't imagine this would be so difficult.  Here's the output from *xorriso -indev ubuntu-20.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso -report_el_torito as_mkisofs* :

```
xorriso : NOTE : Loading ISO image tree from LBA 0
xorriso : UPDATE :     721 nodes read in 1 seconds
xorriso : NOTE : Detected El-Torito boot information which currently is set to be discarded
Drive current: -indev 'ubuntu-20.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso'
Media current: stdio file, overwriteable
Media status : is written , is appendable
Boot record  : El Torito , MBR isohybrid cyl-align-on GPT APM
Media summary: 1 session, 593344 data blocks, 1159m data,  421g free
Volume id    : 'Ubuntu-Server 20.04.2 LTS amd64'
-V 'Ubuntu-Server 20.04.2 LTS amd64'
--modification-date='2021020117574100'
-isohybrid-mbr --interval:local_fs:0s-15s:zero_mbrpt,zero_gpt,zero_apm:'ubuntu-20.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso'
-partition_cyl_align on
-partition_offset 0
-partition_hd_cyl 73
-partition_sec_hd 32
--mbr-force-bootable
-apm-block-size 2048
-iso_mbr_part_type 0x00
-c '/isolinux/boot.cat'
-b '/isolinux/isolinux.bin'
-no-emul-boot
-boot-load-size 4
-boot-info-table
-eltorito-alt-boot
-e '/boot/grub/efi.img'
-no-emul-boot
-boot-load-size 8000
-isohybrid-gpt-basdat
-isohybrid-apm-hfsplus
```

Version information:

```
xorriso 1.5.2
ISO 9660 Rock Ridge filesystem manipulator and CD/DVD/BD burn program
Copyright (C) 2019, Thomas Schmitt <scdbackup@gmx.net>, libburnia project.
xorriso version   :  1.5.2
Version timestamp :  2019.10.26.180001
Build timestamp   :  -none-given-
libisofs   in use :  1.5.2  (min. 1.5.2)
libjte     in use :  2.0.0  (min. 2.0.0)
libburn    in use :  1.5.2  (min. 1.5.2)
libburn OS adapter:  internal GNU/Linux SG_IO adapter sg-linux
libisoburn in use :  1.5.2  (min. 1.5.2)
Provided under GNU GPL version 3 or later, due to libreadline license.
```

I am attempting to assemble a modified boot ISO with custom grub menu opts, user-data and meta-data; following this example:

```
https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/ubuntu-22-04-server-autoinstall-iso/
```

Could someone lend a hand on this one, I'm stumped.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using [Cubic](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic)? Also, see [here for autoinstall](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic/issues/101#issuecomment-1336728758).

Comment: I work in a secure/restricted environment, where we can only use what is there. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I will look into it. We have a limited scope of software we are allowed to use in the environment.

Comment: Curious if you ever happened to get this working, I too am toiling all day trying to make it work properly right now :/